# Wouldn't reality have been destroyed at the beginning of "Endgame"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, infinity-stones

In *Avengers: Endgame*, when Hulk/Banner met the Ancient One in order to get the Time Stone, she refused, saying that if one Infinity Stone is removed from a time period, it would cause problems. I recall her saying that the Infinity Stones create the 'stream of reality'.

When Thanos destroyed the Infinity Stones, wouldn't reality have been destroyed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Sorcerer Supreme says that *removing* the Stones is what causes the flow of time (and reality) to behave oddly.

> **SS:** *The Infinity Stones create what you experience as the flow of time. Remove one of the stones, and that flow splits.*

But Thanos doesn't remove them from the universe, he just reduces them to individual atoms.

> **Black Widow:** *Where are the Stones?*
>
> **Thanos:** ***Gone. Reduced to atoms.***
>
> **Banner:** *You used them two days ago.*
>
> **Thanos:** *I used the Stones to destroy the Stones.*

So the Stones aren't 'removed' so much as '*converted into individual atoms*'. Presumably if you had the wherewithal, you could collect those atoms and re-constitute them into the various Infinity Stones.

Comment: Removing the stones are not the same as destroying the stones though

Comment: @Ginge - I would assume not. Removing them takes them out of the universe entirely. Turning them into dust and spreading that dust across a hundred billion galaxies doesn't cause them to cease to exist, it merely makes them hard to put back together.

Comment: Remove all the Stones, and the flow of time continues until the movie series that depends on it becomes unprofitable!

Answer (score 15):

The Russos have confirmed the stones haven’t been “destroyed”, just atomized in such a way as they don’t exist in the same solid form.

> *"Thanos only reduced the stones to the atomic level. The stones are
> still present in the universe."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Endgame Directors Say That [SPOILER] Still Exist in the Present MCU Timeline](https://www.google.com/amp/s/screenrant.com/avengers-endgame-director-russos-infinity-stones-still-exist/amp/)</sup></sub>

Comment: lol. That's exactly what I said :-P